# Image pop up using jquery fancybox not workig

Tags: jquery

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    nextEffect  : 'fade'

});
```

The above code displays the list of images in a pop box, But i want to display only first six of them of them so i tried as follows

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    i : 1,
    if (i<=6) :{
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    nextEffect  : 'fade'
    },
    i++,
});
```

But it didnt work.... Any help ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below

```
$('.fancybox').each(function(index,ele) {
    if(index < 6)
        $(ele).fancybox({openEffect:'fade',closeEffect:'fade',nextEffect:'fade'});
});
```

Comment: Apologies i got it working , i got it working ...i used photo id for it to be done...rel="gallery{{photo.id}}"... so i dont need to modify the fancy box.... Thank you...